# Flutter: Firebase user's name doesn't get updated when user logs in for the first time

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to fetch a user's ID when a person is logged in with their firebase account. When I try to login a new user for the first time, I can fetch their id however the user's details only reflect after the person navigates from one page to another using the navigation bar. Is there a way I can get rid of that? I want the user's display name to reflect as soon as they create a new account.

This is my current code that I call in my `initState()`

```
 getCurrentUser() async {
        try {
          final user = await _auth.currentUser();
          if (user != null) {
            setState(() {
              loggedInUser = user;
              id = user.uid;
              username = user.displayName;
            });
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      }
```